# Passing a command line argument to jstestdriver JAR from ANT?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ant, js-test-driver

I'm trying to use jstestdriver to generate some unit tests in my ant build in Windows.  I plan to do this by running jstestdriver from an ant target using the <java> ant task.

So far for my ant build file I have the following:

```
 <target name="jstestdriver" description="Runs the js unit tests">
```

```
        ...
```

Now inside the <java> tags ( "..." above) I've tried adding the following:

```
 <arg value="--config" />
 <arg value="../../jstestdriver.conf" />

 <arg value="--tests" />
 <arg value="${whichTests}" />

 <arg value="--testOutput" />    
 <arg value="${reports.dir}" />
```

When I run the jstestdriver target, no messages are displayed on the console, and there are no junit output files in the directory they are to be generated in.

I have also tried the code snippet below instead, which seems to indicate that the jar is being executed:

```
 <arg value="--config ..\..\jstestdriver.conf" />
 <arg value="--tests ${whichTests}" />
 <arg value="--testOutput ${reports.dir}" />
```

However all it does is display an error message:

```
  "--config ..\..\jstestdriver.conf" is not a valid option
```

...and additionally displays a list of options for the jstestdriver jar.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's likely that you want to break each argument and its value into separate arguments. E.g.:

```
<arg value="--config" />
<arg value="..\..\jstestdriver.conf" />
<arg value="--tests" />
<arg value="${whichTests}" />
<arg value="--testOutput" />
<arg value="${report.dir}" />
```

Comment: Found it!  It was a mis-spelled property name...it caused it to have no output.

Comment: It was report.dir not reports.dir :-p

Comment: I think the default for runnerMode is SILENT, so when you set it to DEBUG, you should be able to see error messages

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting runnerMode to DEBUG?